# Merging Two Trees

Tags: c#, tree

I am having following class in my application.

```
public class Employee
{
    public Employee[] ChildOrg {get; set;}
    public string Name {get; set;}
}
```

I am having two instance of that class in my application some what having following hierarchy.

```
objEmployee1
```

[image]

```
objEmployee2
```

[image]

Here i am showing the simple hierarchy. But it may contain any complex hierarchy.

**How can i merge this two tree hierarchy so it looks something like following?**

[image]

I am just knowing that both the tree will have same root node.

I already looked at following link.

[Merging Treenodes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/866380/merging-treenodes)

But still i am unable to understand?

Please help me to create some good algorithm so i can merge two Trees.

Comment: You want to 'merge' all elements of the same level? i.e. all sub-employees of all trees just below the root employee in the result tree?

Comment: This seems to be an exact duplicate and the duplicate you linked to has a working answer with code. Therefore I'm closing this. Request a reopen if you disagree.